# My npm is not compatible with the package.json after switching to Linux?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, npm

I recently switched to Pop! OS Linux on my macbook pro 11,1 (2013) and upon trying to clone into my github repo and install the npm packages, I receive this error:

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/danielvillegas/.npm/_logs/2021-05-25T01_48_00_584Z-debug.log
```

I did install the latest version of npm onto the new system which is currently
`$ npm --version // 6.14.8`.

So it seems like I was able to fix the problem by deleting the package-lock.json and then reinstalling with `npm install`. But... Is there a way I can avoid this issue in the future? I'm not sure what the root of it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to fix package-lock.json lockfileVersion so npm uses a specific format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813775/is-there-any-way-to-fix-package-lock-json-lockfileversion-so-npm-uses-a-specific)