# npm install not working: "npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER"

Tags: node.js, npm

I can't install modules for my react app, when i run `npm i` it does this:

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\setprototypeof-b857a2ac\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\setprototypeof-b857a2ac\index.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\setprototypeof-b857a2ac\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\setprototypeof-b857a2ac\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\rc-5aecd98b\test\ini.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\setprototypeof-b857a2ac\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\rc-5aecd98b\test\nested-env-vars.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\rc-5aecd98b\test\test.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\term-size-f230f088\vendor\windows\term-size.exe'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\ast-types-5383d6cc\def\type-annotations.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\marco\Code\backend\node_modules\.staging\ast-types-5383d6cc\def\typescript.js'
npm WARN backend@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN backend@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/util-deprecate/-/util-deprecate-1.0.2.tgz failed, reason: 4376:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:308:
npm ERR!
```

I tried reinstalling npm and it does the same thing. I tried with another project and I'm getting the same error. I found another question where someone had the same problem but noone replied. I even tried to set the npm registry to `http://registry.npmjs.org` instead of `https://registry.npmjs.org`, and setting the `strict-ssl` option to false, but it still won't work.
My npm version is `6.14.13` and my node version is `v14.17.1`.
Any help?
P.S.: I'm not using a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution would be to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, so that when you reinstall the packages, they get installed with the `lockfileVersion@1`  instead of `lockfileVersion@2`.

I wouldn't suggest that solution though, as if you work in a team you would be forcing the others to do the same in order to fix it.

The problem is the npm version `v6.x.x` supports `lockfileVersion@1` while `v7.x.x` supports `lockfileVersion@2`.

So a better solution would be to simply update your npm version to a v7 and higher.

Here you can find an interesting related discussion about it: [Is there any way to fix package-lock.json lockfileVersion so npm uses a specific format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813775/is-there-any-way-to-fix-package-lock-json-lockfileversion-so-npm-uses-a-specific)

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work...

Comment: So if you run `npm -v` you have npm version `7.x.x`? And with that it still doesn't work?