# NPM v7+ - How to install packages with "lockfileVersion": 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package-lock.json

I updated NodeJS to v16, and it ships with NPM v8, so when I install packages, `package-lock.json` file is created with `"lockfileVersion": 2`. I would like to stay with old format of `"lockfileVersion": 1`. Can we install packages in NPM v8, but keep the version of `package-lock.json` to 1?

Comment: You are totally right, I updated question title and text. Tnx. @CherryDT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to fix package-lock.json lockfileVersion so npm uses a specific format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813775/is-there-any-way-to-fix-package-lock-json-lockfileversion-so-npm-uses-a-specific)

Comment: It does not. As you see in accepted answer, they are downgrading Node locally to do it. I am asking if I can do it with new version of Node and NPM.

Comment: What happens if you `npm i -g npm@6`

Comment: We handled this at a job by installing v8 and v6 back and forth using the above command, depending on project.  Yay?

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that, but I wanted to know if I can install packages with `v8`, but keep `lockfileVersion` to 1, without downgrading npm each time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can find thorough answers to this question at [Is there any way to fix package-lock.json lockfileVersion so npm uses a specific format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813775/is-there-any-way-to-fix-package-lock-json-lockfileversion-so-npm-uses-a-specific) . Using lockfileVersion 2 should be backwards compatible all the way back to at least NodeJS 6+ so im not sure why you would want to use version 1, but if you must there are solutions provided on the linked post.

Comment: I am contributing to one library and they want to stay with version 1.