# is that possible to using the lockfile version 1 in node 16

Tags: npm

Today I found when I using `npm update` command, it upgrade the package lock file version to 2 siliently automatically, is it possible to keep the specify lock file version? or keep the old lock file version? I only want to use the lock file version 1:

[image]

or is there any way to lock the lock file version?

Comment: I think you can find the answer on this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813775/is-there-any-way-to-fix-package-lock-json-lockfileversion-so-npm-uses-a-specific